# Is it "you, who refuses" or "you, who refuse" or other?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, relative-clauses

I'm writing a piece in the second person and I've stumbled on a weird complexity of grammar that I can't wrap my head around. My original sentence in the first draft:

"You, who refuse to even think his name, understand suddenly why he was the man chosen for such a task."

On a reread, this doesn't seem grammatically sound. When referring to the reader in the third person to give extra information, which should it be?

"You, who refuse to even think his name, understand..."

"You, who refuses to even think his name, understand..."

"You, whom refuse to even think his name, understand..."

"You, whom refuses to even think his name, understand..."

Or something else?

Comment: *who*  is the subject of the clause "who refuses to ...." so the nominative *who* is correct and not the objective *whom*. The second person pronoun *you* is the antecedent of *who*, so the verb must be second person *refuse*.

Comment: thank you friend :)